# How do I implement polymorphism with std::shared_ptr?

Tags: c++11, gcc, casting, polymorphism, shared-ptr

*I have seen some of the other questions on this topic, but have still not found the answer - I guess I'm missing something:*

I defined two simple test classes:

```
class TestBase
{

  public:

    TestBase ( ) { };
    ~ TestBase ( ) { };

  protected:

    inline virtual int getInt ( )
    {
        return 0;
    }

};

class TestDerived : public TestBase
{

  protected:

    inline int getInt ( ) override
    {
        return 1;
    }

};
```

I declared typedefs to simplify their usage with `std::shared_ptr:`

```
typedef std::shared_ptr<TestBase> spBase;
typedef std::shared_ptr<TestDerived> spDerived;
```

Problem: I cannot compile code to use these `shared_ptr` declarations polymorphically, even though `base` in all these cases is actually an instance of `spDerived`:

> ```
> spBase base;
> spDerived derived = static_cast < spDerived > ( base );
> ```
>
> ***error: no matching function for call to ‘std::shared_ptr::shared_ptr(spBase&)***
>
> ```
> spDerived derived = dynamic_cast < spDerived > ( base );
> ```
>
> ***error: cannot dynamic_cast ‘base’ (of type ‘spBase {aka class std::shared_ptr}’) to type ‘spDerived {aka class
>   std::shared_ptr}’ (target is not pointer or reference)***
>
> ```
> spDerived derived = static_pointer_cast < spDerived > ( base );
> ```
>
> ***error: conversion from ‘std::shared_ptr >’ to non-scalar type
>   ‘spDerived {aka std::shared_ptr}’ requested***
>
> ```
> spDerived derived = dynamic_pointer_cast < spDerived > ( base );
> ```
>
> ***error: conversion from ‘std::shared_ptr >’ to non-scalar type
>   ‘spDerived {aka std::shared_ptr}’ requested***

I'm using C++11 on an Ubuntu 14.04 box with the default GCC tool chain. Compiler is gcc-4.9.
What am I doing wrong? Can't a shared_pointer be used polymorphically?

Comment: `static_pointer_cast<spDerived::element_type>(base)`

Comment: This is why typedefs like that are a terrible idea. They only make code vastly more confusing.

Comment: @Puppy - I hate so much typing, but I'm afraid you are correct.

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki you save my day!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

A type passed in to [`std::static_pointer_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/pointer_cast) and [`std::dynamic_pointer_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/pointer_cast) as the first type template argument is the type of the converted pointer's type itself, not of the *smart* pointer type:

```
static_pointer_cast<T>(arg);
                .~~~^  
                v 
template <class T, class U> 
           .~~~~^  
           v 
shared_ptr<T> static_pointer_cast(const shared_ptr<U>& r);


dynamic_pointer_cast<T>(arg);
                .~~~~^  
                v 
template <class T, class U> 
           .~~~~^  
           v 
shared_ptr<T> dynamic_pointer_cast(const shared_ptr<U>& r);
```

With that said, you could call it like below:

```
spBase base = std::make_shared<TestDerived>();
spDerived derived = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<spDerived::element_type>(base);
// or:
spDerived derived2 = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<TestDerived>(base);
```