# Smart pointer polymorphism in collections

Tags: c++, pointers, polymorphism, shared-ptr, initializer-list

I am trying to initialize a collection of pointers to class `A` through an initializer list. However, the initializer list cannot use reference as a template type.

I have the following code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <memory>

struct A
{
    virtual void f() const noexcept { std::cout << "A"; }
};

struct B : public A
{
    virtual void f() const noexcept override { std::cout << "B"; }
};

class Test
{
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<A>> vec;
public:
    Test(const std::initializer_list<A>& list)
    //Test(const std::initializer_list<A&>& list) <------ Solution?
    {
        for (auto& x : list)
            vec.push_back(std::make_shared<A>(x));
    }
    void print()
    {
        std::for_each(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](auto x) { x->f(); });
    }
};

int main()
{
    Test test = { A(), B() };
    test.print();
}
```

The code prints:

> AA

It should print:

> AB

Is there a simple way to do this, without having to create pointers in the calling method?

The related article ([How do I implement polymorphism with std::shared_ptr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27502968/how-do-i-implement-polymorphism-with-stdshared-ptr)) did not provide much help with this problem.

Comment: Is just using a variadic constructor acceptable, because if so, [wouldn't something like this work](http://ideone.com/4jdhfZ) ? Or is an explicit initializer list a requirement of yours.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::initializer_list<T>` holds the passed objects by value, so there can be no polymorhism. Also `std::make_shared<A>` always makes an object of type `A`, not some type that derives from `A`. You need another approach.

Since you have an arbitrary number of arguments with arbitrary types, you'll probably need a variadic template constructor.

Edit: My code suggestion was way too complicated. The comment by WhozCraig is much better:

> ```
> template<class... Args>
> Test(Args&&... args) :
>     vec { std::make_shared<std::remove_reference_t<Args>>(std::forward<Args>(args))... }
> {
> }
> ```

Answer (score 2):

You are inserting to the vector using `std::make_shared<A>()`. You are copying a bunch of `B` and `A` into a bunch of `A`.

If you want the syntax in your main to work, the simplest way to do that is a template :

```
struct Foo {
    template<typename... Args>
    Foo(Args... args) :
        vec{std::make_shared<Args>(std::move(args))...}
    {}

private:
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<A>> vec;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You're making new `shared_ptr`s on the following line

```
        vec.push_back(std::make_shared<A>(x));
```

It doesn't matter what `x` was, you made a new `A` with its values.

You probably want to create a `shared_ptr<A>` and pass the pointer from `x.get()` to the new empty `shared_ptr<A>`

Comment: This would have to be done in the `main()` method. Is there a way to do this from the constructor?

Comment: I don't have access to a compiler, but can't you do, in the constructor, `vec.push_back(shared_ptr<A>(x.get()));` ? One of the constructors for shared_ptr takes a pointer, so this seems like it should work http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr

Comment: No, because the inputs being passed to the constructor are not `shared_ptr` objects to begin with. You would have to do something more like this instead: `Test test = { std::make_shared<A>(), std::shared_ptr<A>(new B()) };`  Then you could do `vec.push_back(x);`